# uwsgi + apache - Invalid command 'uWSGISocket', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, uwsgi

I have this error:

> Invalid command 'uWSGISocket', perhaps misspelled or defined by a
>   module not included in the server configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin your@email.com
    ServerName voorloopnul.com
    ServerAlias www.voorloopnul.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Location />
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        SetHandler uwsgi-handler
        uWSGISocket 127.0.0.1:3031
    </Location>

   <Location /static>
        SetHandler none
   </Location>

    Alias /static //srv/apps/voorloopnul/voorloopnul/static/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/voorloopnul.com.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Full tutorial: http://voorloopnul.com/blog/setting-up-django-with-apache-and-uwsgi-ubuntu-12-10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you forgot to enable module libapache2-mod-uwsgi with a2enmod

Comment: Thanks. `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-uwsgi` and next:
`sudo a2enmod libapache2-mod-uwsgi` -> `ERROR: Module libapache2-mod-uwsgi does not exist!`

Comment: You can check name of the module in the /etc/apache2/mods-available/ . It could be something like mod_uwsgi.conf/mod_uwsgi.load . Unfortunately I don't have any ubuntu system on hands